# Instantiate generic type using class passed as parameter

Tags: java, spring, generics

I'm not so experienced with generics and I have a problem.
I have two classes, two generic types, that I have to instantiate passing the same class, so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
protected MyNotGenericClass(Class<CommonType> myClass) {
    g1= new GenericType1<myClass>();
    g2 = new GenericType2<myClass>();
}
```

and pass the `CommonType` class to the constructor:

```
new NotAGenericClass(CommonType.class);
```

but it doesn't work because `'myClass' cannot be resolved to a type`.

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Note that is important for me that `NotAGenericClass` is not a generic type because I have to instantiate it using Spring and I could find some difficulties.

Comment: Can you show the whole `Constructor` class so we have more context (and possibly rename it to avoid confusion)?

Comment: @PaulBellora I renamed the constructor to avoid confusion. At the moment the class only consists in a constructor and two instance properties... nothing more

Comment: A bit off topic, but important. Spring supports generic beans and auto wiring https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics. So it makes sense to make your class generic as it was suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your class generic, like this:

```
public class MyClass<T extends CommonType> {

    private GenericType1<T> g1 = new GenericType1<T>();
    private GenericType2<T> g2 = new GenericType2<T>();

    // no constructor needed
```

}

Comment: cant we just make the constructor generic instead of making the class generic ?

Comment: @Gan it's hard to say for sure given the lack of info in the question, but i don't think so: How could you correctly type the fields g1and g2 without typing the class? Unless you used raw types, which is a poor design

Comment: ahh, i see your point now, yeah true, i was not considering g1 andg2 asinstance variables :P.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: If they are local variables, and you are not going to use that type parameter anywhere outside of the constructor (which is unlikely), then yes, you can just use generic constructor instead of generic class.

Comment: @newacct yeah as i said in my reply to Boh i was not considering g1 and g2 as instance variables(which is ofcourse stupid):P  haha, but however if you look thru the question, OP's original question was to make a reference variable as Type Parameter which to my knowledge is not permissable, what do you say ??

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: Yes, just make the constructor generic, parameterized with `<T>`, and then use `T` as the type parameter.

Comment: @newacct mahn, now i am confused, `Yes, just make the constructor generic, parameterized with <T>, and then use T as the type parameter` reflects my answer :P haha, so is my answer valid in this context ?? .. :O

Comment: @Bohemian is there a way to instantiate a class like `MyClass<T extends CommonType>` using spring bean definition file?

Answer (score 0):

**Type parameters** can only be a **Type**(Reference Types i., Class type or Interface Type) but not a **reference variable**.

your code is same as the below code:

```
            String s="12";
        List<s>  list = new ArrayList<s>();
```

the above code is illegal as Type Parameters should be the actual Type (Reference Types) , here s is a reference variable but not a type.
same applies to your code .

**EDIT:**

If you want your constructor to be generic do this:

```
protected <T> Constructor(T myClass) {
    g1= new GenericType1<T>();
    g2 = new GenericType2<T>();
}
```

and your call would be :

```
new Constructor(new CommonType());
new Constructor(new AnotherCommonType());
```

Comment: So what should I do? Do I have to pass (repeat) the type for every generic type constructor?

Comment: @davioooh the ting i dont understand is how would you  be passing a Class to your constructor ?? could you update your question with a test case ?

Comment: @PaulBellora passing a T to the constructor ??

Comment: @PaulBellora i dint really get you, `T` represents a  generic type as you can see . could you be more clear please :)

Comment: Okay: why are you requiring an instance of `T` to be passed into the constructor as the variable `myClass`? You aren't using `myClass` for anything exception type inferrence. Is that the issue here? just call `new <CommonType>Constructor()`. Anyway it's hard to see what the benefit of the generic constructor would be - the other answers here are more realistic (although the OP should really clarify the question).

Comment: @PaulBellora well, OP wanted myclass (reference variable not a reference type) as a type parameter which ASAIK is not possible. my code, doesnt use 'CommanClass.class', i just made my constructor generic, so that any type passed to the constructor will be the Type Argument. correct me if i am wrong with making reference variable as a type parameter :)

Comment: Read my comment again is all I can say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bubble up the parametric type to the othermost class:

```
class Foo<T> {
  private Bar1<T> g1;
  private Bar2<T> g2;
  protected Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
    g1 = new Bar1<T>();
    g2 = new Bar2<T>();
  }
}
```

Note that the only reason to even pass the `clazz` parameter is if you need to do some reflection-oriented operations at runtime.

Comment: not really, you can create generic constructors as well, you dont need to declare your class as generic.

Comment: True, but then you can't use that parameteric type with the member variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use myClass in generics, It is an variable not a class.

example of how to use Generics:

```
public class GenericExample<T> {
        private T genericObject;

        public GenericExample(T genericObject){
            this.genericObject = genericObject;
        }

        public T getGenericObject(){
            return genericObject;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GenericExample<String> gen1 = new GenericExample<String>("This is a String");
        GenericExample<Integer> gen2 = new GenericExample<Integer>(1);

        String format = "value : %s, %s";
        System.out.println(String.format(format, gen1.getGenericObject(), gen1.getGenericObject().getClass()));
        System.out.println(String.format(format, gen2.getGenericObject(), gen2.getGenericObject().getClass()));
    }
}
```

output:

value : This is a String, class java.lang.String

value : 1, class java.lang.Integer